# OSMBonuspack RoadManager NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, osmdroid

I am following this Tutorial for OSMBonuspack : https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1

when I Run the app I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException for line number 47 in the MainActivity.java which is,

```
Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
```

How to write the asyncTask for this exact block?

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.osmbonuspack_tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.OSRMRoadManager;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.Road;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.RoadManager;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Polyline;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.13, -1.63);
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(9);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

    Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
    startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
    startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
    map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

    RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(this);

    ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    waypoints.add(startPoint);
    GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(48.4, -1.9);
    waypoints.add(endPoint);

    Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

    Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this);

    map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0#important-note-about-network-calls

Comment: Thank you for editing the Tutorial

Comment: @ThilinaEkanayaka Please provide an answer on how you corrected the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hello After a quick search on tutorial i came up with the following sollution.

In the Mkergell tutorial he have clearly said you have to do in background.You can take reference in OSMNavigator.

after a few hours of looking code i came up with this sollution, Hopefully this will help you.

```
ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemArray; 
overlayItemArray = new ArrayList<>(); 
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(27.6803, 85.3303);
GeoPoint destinationPoint = new GeoPoint(27.6303, 85.3203);
```

Now add the geopoint in the overlayitem array

```
  overlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem("Starting Point", "This is the starting point", startPoint)); 
  overlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem("Destination", "This is the detination point", destinationPoint));
  getRoadAsync();
```

Next lets make method and call the async from the method.

```
public void getRoadAsync() {
        mRoads = null;
        GeoPoint roadStartPoint = null;
        if (startPoint != null) {
            roadStartPoint = startPoint;
        } else if (myLocationOverlay.isEnabled() && myLocationOverlay.getLocation() != null) {
            //use my current location as itinerary start point:
            roadStartPoint = myLocationOverlay.getLocation();
        }

        ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(2);
        waypoints.add(roadStartPoint);
        //add intermediate via points:
//        for (GeoPoint p:viaPoints){
//            waypoints.add(p);
//        }
        waypoints.add(destinationPoint);
        new UpdateRoadTask().execute(waypoints);
    }
```

Next step, lets make the roadmanager async class

```
 private class UpdateRoadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Road[]> {

        protected Road[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = (ArrayList<GeoPoint>) params[0];
            RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(getActivity());
            return roadManager.getRoads(waypoints);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Road[] roads) {
            mRoads = roads;
            if (roads == null)
                return;
            if (roads[0].mStatus == Road.STATUS_TECHNICAL_ISSUE)
                Toast.makeText(map.getContext(), "Technical issue when getting the route", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if (roads[0].mStatus > Road.STATUS_TECHNICAL_ISSUE) //functional issues
                Toast.makeText(map.getContext(), "No possible route here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              protected Polyline[] mRoadOverlays = new Polyline[roads.length];
            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = map.getOverlays();
            for (int i = 0; i < roads.length; i++) {
                Polyline roadPolyline = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(roads[i], getActivity());
                mRoadOverlays[i] = roadPolyline;
                String routeDesc = roads[i].getLengthDurationText(getActivity(), -1);
                roadPolyline.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name) + " - " + routeDesc);
                roadPolyline.setInfoWindow(new BasicInfoWindow(org.osmdroid.bonuspack.R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, map));
                roadPolyline.setRelatedObject(i);
//                roadPolyline.setOnClickListener(new RoadOnClickListener());
                mapOverlays.add(1, roadPolyline);
                //selectRoad(0);
//                map.invalidate();
                //we insert the road overlays at the "bottom", just above the MapEventsOverlay,
                //to avoid covering the other overlays.
            }
        }
    }
```

Thats all, for more please do take reference from OSMNavigator and follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid performing long running operations on the UI thread. This includes file and network access.

**`StrictMode`** allows to setup policies in your application to avoid doing incorrect things. For example the following setup will crash your application if it violates some of the Android policies. StrictMode should only be used during development and not in your live application.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Put this inside the OnCreate method.